# Ember currentViewBinding on ContainerView

Tags: ember.js

I have been trying to learn Ember and have recently spent a lot of time referencing the [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) code base over on github. Anyway, I wanted to implement something similar to their `modal` views method and don't understand why the `currentViewBinding` isn't working.

The following is combination of information referenced from these links:

- [`Ember.ContainerView` documentation: Binding a view to display](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html)
- [Discourse's `modal_view.js` file on GitHub](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/views/modal/modal_view.js)
- [Discourse's `modal_controller.js` file on GitHub](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/controllers/modal_controller.js)

```coffee
App.HeaderController = Ember.Controller.extend
  templateName: 'application/header'
  needs: ['modal']

  toggleLogin: ->
    console.log "HeaderController.toggleLogin"
    @get('controllers.modal').show(App.LoginView.create())

App.ModalController = Ember.Controller.extend
  show: (view) ->
    @set('currentView', view)

App.ModalView = Ember.ContainerView
  currentViewBinding: 'controller.currentView'

  viewChanged: (->
    console.log "Modal view changed"
  ).observes('controller.currentView')

App.LoginView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: 'modal/login'
```

My views essentially look like this:

```handlebars
<!-- application.hbs -->
{{render header}}
{{outlet}}

<!-- header.hbs -->
<button {{action toggleLogin}}>Login</button>
{{render modal}}

<!-- modal/login.hbs -->
<h2>Login Form!!</h2>
```

When the app initially loads, I get **2** console logs for *"Modal view changed"*, when I click the `{{action toggleLogin}}` button in my header template, nothing happens except for the console message *"HeaderController.toggleLogin"*.

What am I doing wrong or is this not how the [`Ember.ContainerView` docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html) meant for it to work?

Comment: It looks like `currentView` is being set... but always remains in a `preRender` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Update from `1.0.0-rc.1` to `1.0.0-rc.2`!